# "Cannot find module jquery" in Electron application

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack, vue.js, electron

So I am getting the error "Cannot find module jquery" in my Electron application. In my index.ejs file I have the code:

```
      window.jQuery = window.$ = require('jquery');
```

Inside of a script tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `jquery` as a dependency to your `app/package.json`.

Change directory to `app` and run

```
npm i jquery --save
```

or if you are using yarn

```
yarn add jquery
```

It should look something like this afterwards.

```
{
  "name": "vueelectron",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "An electron-vue project",
  "main": "./dist/main.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "vue": "^2.1.10",
    "vue-electron": "^1.0.6",
    "vue-resource": "^1.0.3",
    "vue-router": "^2.1.2",
    "vuex": "^2.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "author": ""
}
```

Comment: worked like a charm! I had forgot to use --save in my original project so when I did npm install on my new project it didnt install jquery. Thanks Bert!